# Hacking Chrome speech-to-text API to use my own service

Tags: c, api, webkit, google-api

Is it possible to hack the Chrome (more precisely the Webkit's), through an extension, in order to use my own media server instead of Google's one?

It's needed to make realtime voice interactive app and I'm looking to an alternatives instead of doing this in flash or a Java Applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found (for my projects) that using [VideoIO.swf](http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/) and [RTMPLite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) is far easier and more portable solution.